# is $[0,i]$ a normalized vector?

Tags: vectors

I was wondering, is $[0,i]$ a normalized vector?

How about $[0,-i]$?

I believe that they are, but am wondering if someone can verify that.

Edit: sorry for the ambiguity, I meant L2 norm.

Comment: If "normalized" means "norm one", and your norm is $\|(x,y)\| = (|x|^2+|y|^2)^{1/2}$, then YES.  Otherwise, perhaps not.

Comment: What domain are you working on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. $$(|x|^2+|y|^2)^{1/2}=1$$

This  is true for the L2 norm.

Comment: Should the absval go on the outside of the $x^2$? Plugging in i doesn't seem to give the right result as it is.

Comment: That is not really an absolute value, it is the complex norm. So $|i|=1$

Comment: Oh got it. Wolfram confirms. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Basically given a complex number $z=r e^{i\theta}$, $|z|=r$

Comment: Glad it helped.